# How can I center my div horizontally, and have other text on the same line?

Tags: css

My goal is to create a nav bar, perfectly centered horizontally at the top of a screen, with some text in the left hand corner.

I have seen a lot of questions/solutions to horizontal centering, but I'd like to understand how I can 'ignore' the elements to the left or right of what I'm trying to center rather than using the remaining available space.
[image: Here is what it looks like right now]

```css
body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.centerable {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: .5rem;
    width: 80%;
}

h3 {
    color: darkslategray;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

li {
    background-color: slategray;
    border: slategray solid .2rem;
    border-radius: .1rem;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: -.1rem;
    padding: .5rem .5rem;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}

ul {
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#topbar {
    background-color: #fff2ee;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px #DBCFCB;;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>See Your Code</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="divided.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <h3>Code Writer</h3>
        <div class="centerable">
        <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
            <li>Display</li>
        </ul>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the h3 element out of the document flow by using position absolute. If it is not in the document flow, it will not have any impact on the centering of the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```css
body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.centerable {
    position: relative;
    top: .5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    background-color: slategray;
    border: slategray solid .2rem;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: .5rem .5rem;
    position: relative;
}

h3 {
    color: darkslategray;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 5px 0;
}



#topbar {
    background-color: #fff2ee;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px #DBCFCB;;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>See Your Code</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="divided.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <h3>Code Writer</h3>
        <div class="centerable">
        <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
            <li>Display</li>
        </ul>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will be helpful for you

```css
body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.centerable {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: .5rem;
    width: 80%;
}

h3 {
    color: darkslategray;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

li {
    background-color: slategray;
    border: slategray solid .2rem;
    border-radius: .1rem;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: -.1rem;
    padding: .5rem .5rem;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}

ul {
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#topbar {
    background-color: #fff2ee;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px #DBCFCB;;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.centerable{
    position:fixed;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>See Your Code</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="divided.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <div style="margin-top:50px;"><h3>Code Writer</h3></div>
        
        <div class="centerable">
            <ul>
                <li>HTML</li>
                <li>CSS</li>
                <li>JavaScript</li>
                <li>Display</li>
            </ul>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```